# Does the c command create a row vector or a column vector by default in R

Tags: r

In R, when I use a command like this:

```
b <-c(7,10)
b
```

Does it create a row vector (1 row, 2 cols) or a column vector (1 col, 2 rows) by default?

I can't tell from the displayed output.
I am R beginner (as is obvious :))

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Neither. A vector does not have a dimension attribute by default, it only has a length.

If you look at the documentation on matrix arithmetic, `help("%*%")`, you see that:

> Multiplies two matrices, if they are conformable. If one argument is a
>   vector, it will be promoted to either a row or column matrix to make
>   the two arguments conformable. If both are vectors of the same length,
>   it will return the inner product (as a matrix).

So R will interpret a vector in whichever way makes the matrix product sensible.

Some examples to illustrate:

```
> b <- c(7,10)
> b
[1]  7 10
> dim(b) <- c(1,2)
> b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
> dim(b) <- c(2,1)
> b
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]   10
> class(b)
[1] "matrix"
> dim(b) <- NULL
> b
[1]  7 10
> class(b)
[1] "numeric"
```

A matrix is just a vector with a dimension attribute. So adding an explicit dimension makes it a matrix, and R will do that in whichever way makes sense in context.

And an example of the behavior in the context of matrix multiplication:

```
> m <- matrix(1:2,1,2)
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
> m %*% b
     [,1]
[1,]   27
> m <- matrix(1:2,2,1)
> m %*% b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]   14   20
```

Comment: ...with some bias towards treating it as a column vector? `t(b)` is a row vector, after all.

Answer (score 8):

You can treat a vector ( c() ) in R as a row or a column.
You can see this by

```
rbind(c(1,3,5),c(2,4,6))
cbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
```

It is a collection. By default tho when casting to a data frame

```
data.frame(c(1,2,3))
```

it is made a column, such where the first index will address which column of the table is being referenced, in contradiction to what is orthodox in linear algebra.

i.e., to access the hello in this casting of a vector into a data.frame
an additional index is required

```
a = data.frame(c("hello","F***ery"))
a[[1]][[1]]
```

and this is where things get wacky, because data frames don't chive with strings... the type of "hello" is supposedly an integer, with levels...

Comment: A few problems: there is not a strict equivalence between `c` and being a vector; a vector is not at all like a collection, in the mathematical sense; data.frames have accessors that align perfectly with intuition from matrix algebra (try `a[1,]` and `a[1,1]` for your examples). `a[1]` and `a[[1]]` are additional accessors that no one promised would align with matrix algebra; nor should anyone expect them to, since "data.frame" is not a notion from matrix algebra.

Comment: Yeah, I was tripping over the naming a little bit. I use vector here in the Java sense...

Answer (score 2):

The `c` function creates an "atomic" vector, using the word of Norman Matloff in the art of R programming:

> atomic vectors, since their components cannot be broken down into
>   smaller components.

It can be seen as a "concatenation" (in fact `c` stands for concatenate) of elements, indexed by their positions and so no dimensions (in a *spatial* sense), but just a continuous index that goes from 1 to the length of the object itself.

Comment: `is.atomic( c(1,list(2)) ) # FALSE` In any case, the question is narrower than "What does `c` do?"